# JSON result from mysql tabl

Tags: node.js

I need to write an API in nodejs to showing JSON result from mysql tables. I want little hint. I am .net experienced developer but new in Nodejs

any sample code to get similar result will be enough for me.

Best Regards,

[Screenshots of Requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb0qO.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.